# Would a large variance in only one variable also yield a larger correlation coefficient?

Tags: correlation, variance

I'm still learning statistics and am trying to understand the relationship between variance and correlations to generate accurate hypotheses for a study.  After reading around, I get that the larger the variance, the correlation coefficient will be (i.e. pearson's r).  But does this "variance" only refer to the covariance?  Or would a higher variance in only 1 variable, also yield a larger r?  Why?

For example...

Let's say I know from prior research that one variable (call it X1) has a much larger variance than another variable (let's call it X2), but I know nothing about variable Y that I want to measure.

Is it correct to say that the correlation between X1 and Y will be larger in magnitude than the correlation in X2 and Y?  (Because the larger variance yields a larger pearson's r???)

I find it confusing because I see papers say things like "It is well known among statisticians that, other things being equal, the value of r will be greater if there is more variability among the observations than if there is less variability" [(Goodwin & Leech, 2006)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.3200/JEXE.74.3.249-266?casa_token=rayEpHFBvwYAAAAA:cZcSjuUAjWZ7zGtJXsa7FFu5tPfhorEc1EL-nD_IzdFOLl0hLqRJpWVTLp97UwdHYDXCeYIPZp1cHg)

...But if the formula for the correlation coefficient has the standard deviation  in the denominator, then wouldn't a larger standard deviation (& hence variance) mean a smaller correlation coefficient??

Comment: The comment doesn't refer to different pairs of variables, but the same two variables under two sets of conditions where one or both variables is "allowed" or "observed" to vary more but the variability about the (identical) linear relation is the same in both conditions.

Comment: @Glen_b That’s a confusing idea. Could you please give an example?

Comment: Actually I think that an example may be covered by another post on site; if I don't locate that, I'll try to post an answer

Comment: I'm little confused too.  Is your first comment referring to the Goodwin quote when you say "the comment"?